# how to get ComboBox items count

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I'm trying to get an combobox items count using the following code. It doesn't give an error nor the the right amount of count. I guess I have to convert int to string, but how?

```
ComboBox1->ItemIndex = 1;
int count = ComboBox1->Items->Count;
Edit1->Text =  "Count: " + count;
```

Comment: What are you expecting count to be and what is displayed in Edit1->Text?  How are you adding items to ComboBox1 and how many items have you added?

Comment: im sorry i dont no, im very now to Embarcadero RAD Studio XE2. i have create a VCL application

Comment: @shf301 it should be 30 and the Edit1->Text = ""

Comment: @Power-Mosfet check my answer - i have tailored it to the Embarcadero environment and should work for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

```
 int count = ComboBox1->Items->Count;
```

returns the numnber of string items in your TComboBox. You need to check this before setting

```
ComboBox1->ItemIndex = 1;
```

as ItemIndex is used to set the selected item in the combo box and is zero counted. To convert the integer to string in Embarcadero you can use `IntToStr()` function

```
Edit1->Text = "Count:" + IntToStr(count)
```

You will need `#include "System.hpp"` to access that function

Answer (score 3):

```
ComboBox1->ItemIndex = 1;
int count = ComboBox1->Items->Count;
Edit1->Text =  "Count: " + count;
```

Here `"Count: " + count` is an expression where `"Count: "` decays to pointer to first element of the string,  `count` is added to that pointer, with the result that it either points somewhere within the string (OK) or off the end of the string (generally Undefined Behavior).

Regarding the use of your `ComboBox1`, you haven't shown its declaration, and you haven't mentioned which GUI framework, if any, you're using.

So nothing can be said about it without *guessing* what it is.

In order to create formatted text with inserted textual value presentations, you can use e.g. a `std::ostringstream` from the `<sstream>` header, like this:

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << "Count: " << count;
Edit1->text = stream.str().c_str();
```

The call to `.c_str()` may or may not be necessary, depending on what `Edit1.text` accepts.

Answer (score 2):

```
ComboBox1->ItemIndex = 1; 
int count = ComboBox1->Items->Count;
Edit1->Text =  "Count: " + count;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no any need to go through all this jugglery. A simple function is available for that.

```
int count = ComboBox1.GetItemCount();
```